# My C#asp.net project can load pdf report in Windows7 IIS, but it can not load pdf report in Windows10 and windows Server 2012 r2 IIS

Tags: iis-8

My project can load report viewer from release in Virtual Studio 2015 and hosting Windows 7 IIS7.5 local host.
But This project could not load pdf report in other windows of IIS hosting. Windows 10 and Windows Server 2012 R2.
How could I do in Configuration.

Comment: You should add some information about your configuration

Answer (score 0):

1. Please check Browser settings or Add the URL in IE -> Tools -> Compatibility View Settings
2. Take your server and run inetmgr -> Your Server Name -> MIME Types -> Check .pdf extension is there, otherwise add it.